# How to adjust the space between paragraph in a flow document by programming

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I'm a beginer in C# Wpf and I want to make a flow document with few paragrah by programming.
The problem is that there is a big space between pagraphs and i want to resize it to its minimum.

I found a solution by using a Xml statement, but i want to make it by programming :

```
<FlowDocument>
  <FlowDocument.Resources>
    <!-- This style is used to set the margins for all paragraphs in the FlowDocument to 0. -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
  </FlowDocument.Resources>

  <Paragraph>
    Spacing between paragraphs is caused by margins set on the paragraphs.  Two adjacent margins
    will "collapse" to the larger of the two margin widths, rather than doubling up.
  </Paragraph>

  <Paragraph>
    To eliminate extra spacing between two paragraphs, just set the paragraph margins to 0.
  </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

How can i do it ?.

thanx for you're help.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(Paragraph));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Block.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0)));
myFlowDocument.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), style);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me nor does setting the Margin property in code (i.e. `paragraph.Margin = new Thickness(0)`). Nothing I do seems to want to reduce paragraph spacing.

Comment: This is years after the fact but in Visual Studio 2017/ WPF this worked perfectly. It removes the extra space between paragraphs and still allows me to create bulleted lists onclick in the code.

Answer (score 3):

No "programming" is necessary.  The `PagePadding` property on `FlowDocument` worked for me:

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="0">
```

[MSDN definition for PagePadding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument.PagePadding);k(vs.objectbrowser);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates the thickness of padding space between the boundaries of a page and the page's content.

Comment: Yes im still using WPF, it's very powerful for its secret uses.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above answers but this somewhat solved my problem.

I create the flowdocument object and attach it to the flowdocument viewer.

therefore i used this method. which described here but using code.
[How to: Adjust Spacing Between Paragraphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-adjust-spacing-between-paragraphs?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

```
       paragraph2.Margin = new Thickness(0);
       paragraph3.Margin = new Thickness(0);
```